# How would ubuntu 14.04 run on my hardware

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, hard-drive, hardware

So I'm very new to Ubuntu. I'm building a new computer to run on Ubuntu and I'm just wondering how Ubuntu 14.04 would run on the following hardware I have purchased:

- 4gb DDR3 ram
- AMD Phenom 2 Quad Core 2.5 GHz to 3.7 GHz (not sure)
- EVGA Nvidia GForce GT 610
- WD Blue 1TB Desktop Hard Disk Drive - 7200 RPM SATA 6 Gb/s 64MB Cache

Comment: You will really want more ram. 4 isn't a lot these days. That will get full pretty quickly.

Comment: It would run like greased lightening if you added a solid state disk for your OS and programs and kept the HDD for data

Answer (score 2):

It will run fine. I would prefer xubuntu for a touch of a lighter system, but in the end the ram eaters will be the applications like Firefox, whatever system (windows, (x)ubuntu) you are running.

And I would recommend 16.04 of course,since it is the current lts version.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more ram may help but I can say I run a phenom 2 820 i think .. its a quad core 2.8ghz I run a server that runs an android-x86 and Windows 10 VM and a bunch of other stuff and it seems to handle it fine but I did have to bump up my ram to 16g for all I'm running. Its a bit slow on boot and if Windows 10 is chugging along it can be a bit unresponsive but .. I'm really stressing the hardware ... I think you would be fine with that... maybe an upgrade to 8g or 16g ram might help a bit more.

I also agree with the other poster .. I use Xubuntu on the server I mentioned above

Comment: 14.04 is not past life.... Its an LTS. While there is a newer LTS out, 14.04 is still alive and valid on this site.

Comment: you are  right  for some reason i was looking at it as 15 even tho i wrote 14 and my mind didn't click right gotta stop answering when im asleep